# MySQL ISNULL with INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, ifnull

I have 2 tables: "shares" and "pending_share_changes". The "shares" table has the following columns:

```
share_ID, asset_ID, member_ID, percent_owner, is_approved
```

pending_share_changes has the following columns:

```
share_change_ID, asset_ID, member_ID, percent_owner, is_approved, requested_by
```

I have a form (php) which lists the pending changes which the members have to approve or deny. Everything works fine unless the member has no existing shares, which means there is no record in the "shares" table for them. The query I am using to view the pending share changes is as follows:

```
SELECT p.share_change_ID, assets.asset_desc, assets.asset_value, shares.percent_owner AS 
          percent_owner_old, p.percent_owner 
          FROM pending_share_changes as p
          inner join assets on assets.asset_ID = p.asset_ID
          inner join shares on shares.asset_ID = p.asset_ID AND shares.member_ID = p.member_ID
          INNER JOIN orgs ON orgs.org_ID = assets.org_ID
          WHERE orgs.org_ID = '$org_ID' AND p.member_ID = '$member_ID' AND p.is_approved = '0'
```

I tried using IFNULL(shares.percent_owner, 0) AS percent_owner_old but that didn't work. The query returns no results. I would like to have the percent_owner_old column display a "0" if there is no record in the shares table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your join to `shares` from an `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT ....
FROM pending_share_changes p
....
LEFT JOIN shares ON shares.asset_ID = p.asset_ID AND shares.member_ID = p.member_ID
```

This means "for every `member_ID` and `asset_ID` in `p`, join it to the matching row in `shares`. If the `member_ID`/`asset_ID` exists in `p` but not `shares`, make a row anyway and set the corresponding values to `NULL`".

The `INNER JOIN` means to only show joined rows where the relevant record exists in *both* tables.

Then you can combine with the `IFNULL(shares.percent_owner,0) AS percent_owner_old`.

Comment: That was the trick. I need to read up on left join/inner join some more. Thanks!!